# How durable are Dr. Strange's Mandalas of Light in the movie?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, doctor-strange

Now that the movie has been released, is there any evidence of how strong his light shields are?

If at all possible, I prefer feats that are performed after he masters the use of magic, not when he was still training.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so I'm trying to think of a way to answer this without spoiling the film for those who may not have seen it.

The mandalas he created consistently got stronger through the film (which I'm sure you expected), but they weren't mastery level strong by the end of the film, and they didn't need to be because the resolution to the story made use of a different kind of power. The general feeling I got is that he still has some learning to do because his abilities haven't completely matured. We have more to this part of his character arc to look forward to in subsequent films.

I'm not familiar with the comics, so I don't know how the stories compare, but as a film, I do recommend it.

Comment: If you want, you can include spoilers with the >! markdown.

Comment: @Adamant - Thanks for the tip

Answer (score -1):

They aren't called the Mandalas of Light. I understand why you think that BTW, but they are called the Ruby Rings of Raggador and they are quite strong, depending on the size of the shields. If they're smaller it's faster to block, but the durability sucks. When he makes them bigger they are able to withstand blasts from Dormammu. Honestly the Eldrtich Magic or "Dr. Strange's magic" is quite confusing in how it works.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It looks like you've buried your answer in the middle; you really should begin with the answer, and only after correct the question's terminology.  Also "the durability sucks" isn't a great quantification of how durable they are; can you be more precise?

Comment: The Rings of Raggaddor are a completely different thing. Also, they're not called that in the MCU